# trying to center images in galleria jquery

Tags: jquery, css, galleria

i am using jquery galleria which is quite cool but i can't seem to figure out how to center the list of thumbnails.  asyou can see in the below link, the main image is centered but the thumbnails are always left justified.  any css experts know what i am doing wrong here.

Here is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list items are currently set to "display: block; float: left;" which is causing your problem as centring the content will do nothing to these...

There is a solution though.

As all of your images in the thumbnail section will always be the same width, you can make an adjustment to get things centred.

I made the following change to your CSS

```
.gallery_demo {
  padding-left: 80px;
  width: auto;
}
```

Which seems to get the results you are after.

p.s. the "center" html tag shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1):

To center the galleria thumbnails under the large image, I added the following to my site's css file:

.galleria-thumbnails {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

Comment: This worked for me - I have both land scape and portrait thumbs hence a variable width. The accepted answer above 'seems' specific to that OP - this answer should work for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use jquery to get the width of the container then make the padding-left the equation does this make sense? – ((widthOfGalleria - widthOfThumbnailsList)/2)